# is there a reason that most/all try-catch examples are only using void-sub-functions for the throw statement

Tags: c++, try-catch, compiler-warnings, throw, noreturn

all around I am seeing sample code like this (not tested for compile) on the try-except and throw statement as present in most c++ implementations:

```
void subfunction(int a)
{
  throw;
}
void function(int a)
{
  try
  {
    subfunction(a)
  }
  catch(...)
  {
  }
}
```

I am now wondering if there is any good reason why the equivalent of `function()` or `subfunction()` is (nearly) always in this samples realized as a void in this samples. is there a particular reason or impact with respect to the three mentioned special `c++` keywords? what would the implication on warnings like "function is missing a return statement", "not all control paths return a value" and likes be? is the keyword "throw" somewhere internally label'ed as `noreturn` or similar (as can be found on "exit()" for some compilers)?

PSI i am currently on MSVS 2012 with according MSVC but I am using other compilers as well such as GNUC in its various current versions.

Comment: An exception is not a variable that you can return. To throw an exception upper, you do not need anything to return.

Comment: If the catch(...) doesn't throw, it is perfectly valid to put a return statement after the catch{} block in a function that returns a value.  If the catch throws or re-throws, no return value is expected any more.  The execution path is altered by the throw out of the function, and the throw will fall to the nearest catch outside of the function.

Comment: Sounds like you need better learning resources if examples like this are all you've found!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`throw` can be used in non void-function.

`throw` "has" the `noreturn` attribute so should not provoke warning about *"not all control paths return a value"* for code similar to

```
double my_div(double a, double b)
{
    if (b == 0.) {
         throw std::runtime_error("division by zero");
         // No warning here
    } else {
         return a / b;
    }
}
```